# Which one is right "Comment" or "Comments"

Tags: word-usage

On webpages ( in contact-us forms and comment boxes ) plural and singular for of comment and comment/comments are variably used.

1) Add a comment

2) Submit comment

3) Post comments

etc

On facebook, it's a button "comment" ( besides like button )

What is right. Plural or singular form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the first option is correct since "a" implies one -- one comment.  The third option is also correct.  It is just more encouraging to provide more than a single comment.  The second is the most awkward to me. It seems slangy.  I would have expected it to either say "Submit a comment" or "Submit comments".
Contextually, I think they are all basically correct. The singular phrase treats the whole submission as a "comment".  The plural phase acknowledges that there may be multiple observations in the submission.  Use what fits with the rest of your site.

Comment: The middle example is just “heading English” that omits insignificant articles.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context for the action.

A button to allow the entry of (one) comment is properly named [Comment]

A control to display the list of all comments would be properly labelled [Comments] (**show** or **display** is implied)

Since comments are created one at a time, usually singular applies.

Comment: But you can enter multiple comments in one comment field. It's common to ask someone for their comments (plural) on something ("Do you have any comments?") and a form asking for comments is just the same.